# upload file via Data Management API, but return 403

Tags: autodesk-forge

The scope includes data:write data:create, and accessToken can be obtained. But when uploading files through Api, it returns 403 and the message prompt: "No write access".
I checked it according to the [document](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/), which means: "The Authorization was successfully validated but permission is not granted. Don't try again unless you solve permissions first.".
I'm not sure if there is something wrong with the permission when get the accessToken, or because the free user has no permission to call the upload file interface. But it worked normally before.

Comment: you are correct the scope can be data:write or data:create with uploading file. The most possiblity is you are trying to uploading to a bucket which is NOT created by this Forge app. e.g. you may have a few Forge apps (different client id and secret). The bucket may be created by the other Forge app, so this app cannot write the data. Or even the bucket is created by other customers, while you thought you are the owner. Please GET:Buckets firstly to check which buckets available with this app (client id + secret) :https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-GET/

Comment: @XiaodongLiang Thanks very much, you solved my doubts.

Comment: glad to know it answers :)  I posted it as an answer. Could you vote or accept it as answer? It would help others when they search the similar topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are correct the scope can be data:write or data:create with uploading file. The most possibility is you are trying to uploading to a bucket which is NOT created by this Forge app. e.g. you may have a few Forge apps (different client id and secret). The bucket may be created by the other Forge app, so this app cannot write the data. Or even the bucket is created by other customers, while you thought you are the owner. Please GET:Buckets firstly to check which buckets available with this app (client id + secret) :forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-GET